# C# & ASP.NET MVC 5 : optional string in route URL using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to have an optional section of a string in a given route URL using C# and ASP.NET MVC 5.

For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/hot-dogs{withMustard:regex(-with-mustard?)}/", Name = "HotDogOrder")]
public async Task<ActionResult> HotDogOrder(string withMustard= null)
```

I want the route to work for either:

```
https://www.domain.tld/hot-dogs/
https://www.domain.tld/hot-dogs-with-mustard/
```

If I use that regular expression, it will match for `https://www.domain.tld/hot-dogs-with-mustard/`, but not `https://www.domain.tld/hot-dogs/`

I don't want to add the `with-mustard` as what would look like a subdirectory such as:

```
https://www.domain.tld/hot-dogs/with-mustard/
```

Is this even possible? I've tried using an optional `?`, `*`, but can't seem to get this to work. I want to use the `Route` decorators and not have to create different functions for every single option that could be possible.

Any ideas, or is this not possible?

I've tried various regex values and can't seem to find something that will work for both use cases

Comment: A simple Url Parameter `?ingredient=mustard` and a FromUri Attribute on the withMustard parameter?

Comment: I'm looking to limit the possibilities and have a long tail URL instead of querystring parameters.

Comment: Then it would still be a parameter to me but the parameter you give into your endpoint method should be an enum then and not a string.

Comment: Thinking about it actually 'hot-dogs' and 'hot-dogs-with-mustard'  could be the enum values you could use in the route if you dislike parameters. So a `[Route("~/{myLovelyEnumParameter}/", Name = "HotDogOrder")]` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two routes and check for the Path property.
I don't think regex is thinked to work on entire routing, it works on single parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("hot-dogs")]
    [Route("hot-dogs-with-mustard")]
    public ActionResult<string> DoSomething() {
        var path = Request.Path; // 
    }
```

Try also this, works also with something like hot-dogs-with-mustard-ketchup

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("hot-dogs")]
    [Route("hot-dogs{actionPath:regex(^(-with(-(ketchup|mustard|relish))+)$)}")]
    public ActionResult<string> DoSomething(string? actionPath) {
        
        return Ok(actionPath);
    }
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of.  I didn't want to have to generate a million different routes for each possible combination.  So having something like "hot-dogs{condiment:regex(-with-(ketchup|mustard|relish))}" would have been optimal.

Comment: I've added an alternative, with regex I couldn't intercept empty action so I added an express route for "hot-dogs" only. I tried with swagger and it works

Comment: The second snippet you posted will work for my needs.  Thanks a million!